# Does Electric Flux Density due to an external Electric field increase in a dielectric medium as compared to free space?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, polarization, dielectric

There is exactly the same question on StackExchange but I don't find it rigorous or even right per se.

[How flux density increases in the dielectric medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484214/how-flux-density-increases-in-the-dielectric-medium)

In the 7th edition of the book "Elements of Electromagnetics by Matthew N. O. Sadiku"

On page 190 the author goes on to say:

"We now consider the case in which the dielectric region contains free charge.
If $\rho_v$ is the volume density of free charge, the total volume charge density $\rho_t$ is given by:
$$\rho_t = \rho_v + \rho_{pv} = \nabla.\epsilon_0E$$ (Where $\rho_{pv}$ is the volume charge density due to polarization of the dielectric.)

Hence,
$$\rho_v = \nabla.\epsilon_0E - \rho_{vp} = \nabla.(\epsilon_0E + P) = \nabla.D$$

We conclude that the net effect of the dielectric on the electric field $E$ is to increase $D$
inside it by the amount $P$. In other words, the application of $E$ to the dielectric material
causes the flux density to be greater than it would be in free space. "

Now my questions are:

1. I don't exactly get how did the author conclude the electric flux density increases by P from the last equation since E is definitely not the External electric field here, so it's wrong to compare it directly with the electric flux density in free space.
2. $\textbf{And this is my main question}$, if the dielectric did not have free charges, can we say that the electric flux density $D$ $\textbf{remains constant}$?